# Save Object in MYSQL database using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to save a Properties object in mysql database. This is my code for the class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblexample")
public class Example
{
    @Column
    private Properties properties;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I was using `columnDefinition = "OTHER"` when using H2 db. But such option is not provided in MySql. So I wanted to know how does hibernate store my properties object in mysql. Does it store it as a `TEXT/MEDIUMTEXT`? And when i retrieve the value from the database, do i have to convert the value from String to Properties?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont put @JoinColumn anatation on the application field.

I think firstly you should put @JoinColumn anatation and @manytoone/onetoone/onetomany anatation .

Comment: The properties class defined over here is java.util.Properties. I don't have any entity defined for such class.